# How can I search comments on YouTube

Tags: youtube, comments

I am trying to see all the comments a user has made.

For example, I Googled:

```
"User1" site:http://youtube.com/all_comments
```

But apparently this does not work any more. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Although this came up quite a [few times](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45724/117311), there doesn't seem to be a reliable way.

Comment: are you trying to search comments of a specific video or user?

Comment: I just tried https://www.smalltubetools.com, works quite well.

Answer (score 6):

After the integration with Google+, YouTube's comment section is indexed differently. There no longer is an "/all_comments" section for each video. In order to search for comments on Google, you'll change your search query to:

> "Username"* ago site:youtube.com/watch

I made a video explaining how to do it here: [Search YouTube Comments With Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGM5pspk-pU)

Comment: This just plain doesn't work for me.  I tried looking up a comment I made months ago and it doesn't find it. :-(

Comment: They have now also wrecked this.