# How to view someone else's comments on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I want to search for given user's comments. Is there no way to do this considering the user is not me?

The method recommended [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95670/how-can-i-search-comments-on-youtube) does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work about that method? I just tried it and it worked.